# Как с помошью java script обновить страницу с определённым адресом в строке браузера

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой код. Он каждые 3 секунды обновляет страницу. Обновляет он все страницы какие я бы не открыл. Как сделать так, что-бы этот код обновлял страницу с определённым адресом, допустим example.com/picture и никак не реагировал, когда в строке браузера написано что-то другое?

```
 setInterval(function(){
    window.location.reload();
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: Если существующий ответ вам поможет, проголосуйте вверх и поставьте галочку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    // вместо URL вставить тот URL, который вам нужен
    if (location.href === "URL") {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}, 3000);
```

В этом коде просто добавлена проверка URL на соответствие нужному.

Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: Peter Kolosov, спасибо, сейчас проведу испытание

Comment: Peter Kolosov, большое спасибо всё работает как надо.

Comment: @User пожалуйста, проголосуйте за ответ (Стрелочка вверх) и примите ответ (Галочка).

Comment: Я рад, что вам помогло!

Comment: Peter Kolosov, у меня такой ещё вопрос.  Код рабочий, но я тут столкнулся с другой проблемой. Что делать, если моя ссылка имеет вид допустим example.com/123/#hb. Но эта ссылка может меняться. Меняются только цифры после,  example.com/причём количество их тоже может меняться. Пытался подставить символ *  звёздочку, вместо цифр но это не работает.  Что нужно вместо цифр написать? Или тут более сложное решение?)